# Attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'x' (a table value)

Tags: actionscript-3, lua

I'm working with [lua-alchemy](https://code.google.com/p/lua-alchemy/), and I'm setting a global variable in my AS3 code in this way:

```
_lua.setGlobal("map", _map);
```

With _map being a object with the following function in it:

```
public function get x():int
{
    return 10;
}
```

if then I try to do something like this in Lua

```
local a = map.x + 1
```

I get the following error:

```
Lua script failed: luaDoString:21: attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'x' (a table value)
```

Does anyone knows why it does that, and how I could fix it?

**EDIT :**

When I print `type(map.id)`, it prints `table`... Shouldn't it print `number`?

Comment: Have you tried looping through the members of the table to see what they are? Possibly using for k,v in pairs(map.x)?

Answer (score 0):

I found my error. According to [this page](https://code.google.com/p/lua-alchemy/wiki/TypeConversions), I have to use `as3.tolua(map.x)` to convert it to the right type.